# Check if a value exists in an object's list array

Tags: java

Hello I loop while the client types y

and then I wanted to take the value you entered and make sure it's contained in my client list
but I don't know how to do that

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
ArrayList<OrderService> orderService = new ArrayList<OrderService>();
System.out.println("add Cliente name")
string name = scanner.nextLine();
cliente.setName(name);
fazer um loop para se quiser adicionar mais clientes.

System.out.println("starting");

boolean value = true;
while(value)){
    System.out.println("Enter a new Client name");
    string name = scanner.nextLine();
    if(!name && name.trim().equals("")){
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente(name);
        clientes.add(cliente);
        System.out.println("Cliente "+cliente.getName+" Adicionado")
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Nome invalido")
    }
    System.out.println("Do you want to add more client? Y for Yes, N for no");
    string response = scanner.nextLine(); 
    if(!response.equalsIgnoreCase(y)){
        value = false
    }
}

System.out.println("Enter a Client name that you want to create a work order.");
string clientName = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use streams api to easily implement your question
Supposed your `Cliente` class had a `name` property. Based on the comments you have provided, you can use the checkedCliente in the second if statement

```
if(!name && name.trim().equals("")){
    Cliente checkedCliente = clientes.stream()
                .filter(x -> name.equals(x.getName()))    // check name is there?
                .findAny()
                .orElse(null);

    if(checkedCliente == null){
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente(name);
        clientes.add(cliente);
        System.out.println("Cliente "+cliente.getName+" Adicionado")
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Cliente " + cliente.getName() + "is already in the collection");

        // checkedCliente can be used for updates etc in here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Client checkedClient = clients.stream ()
with this if i have this value in my list i will assign to my checkedCliente?

Comment: @Felipe  Indeed, I've updated my answer. Basically you can use the checkedCliente as for update etc purposes.

Comment: thank you bro that's what you needed
get the client if it exists in the list

Comment: You're welcome @Felipe , I highly encourage you to check streams api for collection opearations like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a stream.

```
public static Cliente findByName(Collection<Cliente> clientes, String name)
{
    return clientes.stream().filter(cliente -> name.equals(cliente.getName())).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: in case i can use
Customers.contains (clientName)

even if the client name is in an attribute of the client object?

in my list I save an object and not an array

Answer (score 0):

This is how to check if an arraylist contains a string

```
if(clientes.contains(name))
```

Comment: and how could i pull this value into a variable?

Comment: you can create an ArrayList<String> and add the name to it. I don't really understand what you are trying to ask though.